# Isn't the preposition "aus" redundant in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I have the following sentence which I think has a redundant word:

> Von der Plattform aus hat man eine gute Aussicht über Frankfurt.

Should *aus* be omitted or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. No. Depends.

Yes, omitting the "aus" creates a sentence that sounds well:

> Von der Plattform hat man eine gute Aussicht über Frankfurt.

No, it includes the reference.

Like the explanation on [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Plattform) or [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Plattform):

- 1. ... (von der aus man einen guten Ausblick hat)...
- 3. Basis, Standpunkt, **von dem** bei Überlegungen, Absichten, Handlungen, politischen Zielsetzungen o. Ä. **aus**gegangen wird
- Beispiele [ 1]: Wenn man mit dem Aufzug hoch fährt, kann man *von der Plattform aus* über die ganze Stadt sehen.

So for correct grammar it is needed (to have the reference). It seems natural in spoken language to omit it that it feels not wrong omitting it in written language as well.

[Update: ]
For further reading there is "[redundancy (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics))"(en.wikipedia) to counter-check the feeling of a seemingly superfluous part. There you find easy things like `free gift` and further terms like tautology & pleonasm which build upon "redundant phrases".

[/Update thx to [Cacambo]](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/40690/cacambo)

So I say how you use it depends on your personal style.

Comment: (Aussicht) über die Stadt hin; über die Brücke rüber, durch das Tor hindurch: you will find many expressions, where a word seems superfluous, but nonetheless is commonly used.

Comment: @mic: do you know a word other then "seemingly superfluous" i could look for to integrate it into my answer? (or you post your own). Thanks.

Comment: seemingly redundant?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundanz_(Kommunikationstheorie) Hier findest du vielleicht ein passendes Wort. Pleonasmus, Tautologie, …

Comment: @mic *über die Stadt _hin_* seems strange to me (maybe because of social or regional reasons). Does it mean the same as *über die Stadt _hinweg_* or *bis _jenseits_ der/_hinter_ die Stadt*?

Comment: @Cacambo - "über die Stadt hin" does not automatically mean "hinweg", but includes some sense of moving, like in "der Blick schweifte über die Stadt hin" or "die Vögel flogen über die Stadt hin". The latter may be "hinweg" but also that they are just in search of a good place to go down. I admit it's a bit old style, though.

Comment: @mic Thanks. I would comprehend it as an inflected form of *hinschweifen*, and know it from *hin- und herschweifen*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *aus* or leave it out. The difference in your example would chiefly be the rhythm of the sentence, and so, depending on context, you one time may prefer to add the *aus*, another time you may prefer to go without it.

Another factor to consider might be register of speech. With the "double-up preposition" added you usually get more into casual oral style, whereas without the preposition the sentence tends to sound more formal.

Other example:

> Tausende von Autofahrern fahren in die Innenstadt.

(Normal / formal)

> Tausende von Autofahrern fahren in die Innenstadt rein.

(Clearly sloppily oral; but also more expressive)

Comment: formal version of the latter: *Tausende von Autofahrern fahren in die Innenstadt hinein.*  
Or, if the speaker is inside the city center: *Tausende von Autofahrern fahren (probably "kommen" would fit better) in die Innenstadt herein.*